# Django: How to join columns without foreign key with ORM

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I´m new to Django and Python and I can´t get a solution to this problem, so any help is appreciated!

I´m trying to join Database columns in Django, that do have a corresponding value but that value is not a foreign key.

Let´s say my models are:

```
class Order(models.Model):
   order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   oOrder_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   ...
```

and

```
class Shipment(models.Model):
  dShipment_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  dTo_order = models.CharField(max_length=10)
  ...
```

What I do know is, that I can use Djangos `select_related` command to get the values from tables, that are connected with a foreign key.

But here is my problem: I can not use a foreign key in my model here, for reasons that are rooted in a third party software that is pushing the Data over my API. That software is incapable of storing a return value from the created order and use it as an identifier for the shipment (...).

So finally here is my question: Is it possible to do some join with the identical fields `oOrder_number` and `dTo_order` ?

My desired result is, that I can select a certain Order and get all connected shipments from the Shipment table, that will all have the same dTo_order.

I know how to do this in Larvel and MySQL Querie, but from what I heard it´s not "Djangoish" to use raw querie... .

Any Ideas on that?

Thanks for reading! If i left something out, I will be glad to provide all necessary information! :)

Edit: I know that I could try a workaround to get the Foreign of the order for the shipment by searching the Order table for the To_order field and get the primary key of it. However I am curious if there is a more elegant solution for this in Django.

Update:

Here is what I imagine.

- I fetch order from the DB like `orders=Order.objects.all()`.
- I do some magic so that for every order object, there will be an array or what ever with all the shipments data that belong to the order
- I pass the data to my template. Here I woul then like to do something like:

  {% for order in orders %}

  {{Order.oOrder_no}}

  {% for shipment in order.shipments %}

  {{shipment.trackingno}}

  {% endfor %}

  {% endfor %}

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [`Subquery` expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) with `OuterRef`:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
shipments = Shipment.objects.filter(dTo_order=OuterRef('oOrder_number'))
Order.objects.annotate(shipments=Subquery(shipments.values('dShipment_id', 'trackingno')))
```

Comment: Thanks! If I am getting this right, this will do something like "annotate". But what if i do have multiple shipments to that order, like a many to one relation? :/

I managed to "add" fields to the data set by doing something like this:

os = Shipment.objects.filter(dTo_order=OuterRef('oOrder_number'))
ao = Order.objects.annotate(shipments=Subquery(os.values('dTracking_no')))

But this will only work on a 1:1 relation :/

Comment: If you want shipments of a single order it should be pretty straight-forward like my updated answer above. I don't think you need `OuterRef` here.

Comment: Thanks again! Its just the other way - I want to get the order with all shipments that have the dTo_Order field equal to the Orders oOrder_number. 
This shoul be true for every object in my query.
So in the end I coul to someting like for order.shipments as shipment ...

Comment: Not sure if I follow you.. does my updated answer look like what you want? You first get an `Order` object with certain criteria, and then you filter `Shipment` by matching `dTo_order` to `oOrder_number`.

Comment: So you updated answer will let me with an order object and the corresponding shipment(s) - but not in the same variable. Example: I want to pass Data to my template. Here I do something like foreach order ... and in that loop i want to access the shipments data. I will update my question to make that point clear with some code :)

Comment: I see. In that case you do need `OuterRef`. I've updated my answer accordingly then.

Comment: Thanks for your patience! I think your updated answer corresponds with my comment from 1 hour ago. Executing this query for order with more than one shipment throughs an error: _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1242, 'Subquery returns more than 1 row')

Comment: Does this example work?

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: subquery must return only one column`

Comment: This doesn't work. The annotate does not allow more than one field, like the previous commenters mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data to your template using this without nested loop anymore and this way will reduce processing time:

Using a Subquery expression with OuterRef:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

shipments = Shipment.objects.filter(dTo_order=OuterRef('oOrder_number')).values('trackingno') 
orders = Order.objects.annotate(shipments=Subquery(shipments.values('trackingno')[:1]))
```

Then you can use single for loop like:

```
{% for order in orders %}

{{Order.oOrder_no}}

{{Order.trackingno}}

{% endfor %}
```